# Continued Fraction for $\log(\frac{1+\alpha z}{1+z})$

Tags: generating-functions, continued-fractions

There is a continued fraction for
$$\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$
given by
$$\cfrac{2z}{1-\cfrac{1z^2}{3-\cfrac{4z^2}{\cdots}}}.$$

This was known even to Gauss.
See Handbook of Continued Fractions for Special Functions by Annie A.M. Cuyt et al pg 196
or Analytic theory of Continued fractions by H.S. Wall pg 343.

Is there a continued fraction of the same form for the more general
$$\log\left(\frac{1+\alpha z}{1-z}\right)?$$

Comment: The original result is a special case of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction), again by Gauss. Your last function doesn't seem to be "close" to a quotient of hypergeometric series, so I wouldn't expect a CF "of the same form".

Answer (score 0):

There is
$$
\log \left(\frac{a z+1}{1-z}\right)-\frac{(a+1) z}{1-\frac{\frac{1-a}{2} z}{1-\frac{\frac{(a+1)^2}{6 (1-a)} z}{1-\frac{\frac{a^5-a^4-8 a^3-8 a^2-a+1}{3(-a^4-2 a^3+2 a+1)} z}{1-\ldots}}}}.
$$
Any formal power series can be expanded into a cfrac of the form $a_0+\operatorname{K}\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_nz}{1}$, where coefficients $a_n$ can be determined through Hankel matrices composed of coefficients of the formal power series. But one can not always expect a regular pattern in the coefficients $a_n$.

Comment: Hi there. It's a shame this post got overlooked. This is very interesting to me: could you provide a reference for this Hankel matrix technique?

Comment: Any alternative to the basic Euler continued fraction formula is welcome!